# Create a strategy based on built-in indicators

Tags: pine-script

I can create strategy using built-in methods, like `sma` or `crossover`.
But can I create strategy which is using built-in indicator? Some like that:

```
obv = Indicators.OBV() // Trying to use built-in OBV indicator
obv_sma = sma(obv)

if (crossover(obv, obv_sma)) {
   strategy.entry("OBV is high", strategy.long)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "source input" feature, and select OBV in properties after adding it to chart.

`obv = input(close, type=source)` instead of
`obv = Indicators.OBV()`

Blog post on feature https://blog.tradingview.com/en/new-feature-8211-apply-an-indicator-to-another-indicator-1844/